# React Router component doesn't load but successfully redirects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router v5.2.0 and implementing public / private routes with async authentication.
Essentially the workflow is:
PublicRoute for login,
PrivateRoute for dashboard
and a PublicRoute for /landing (so if a user is logged in, but they aren't subscribed to a service they will be redirected to a landing page).

All of my routes work except for '/landing'
The app will redirect to /landing succesfully, but the Landing component doesn't show / mount. (The console.log will not trigger either)

I am using redux and I've tried adding withRouter but receive the same error.
If I remove the public or private route component and use a regular Route, the component will show.

**App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  
    <Switch>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <PublicRoute exact restricted={true} path="/landing" component={Landing} />
      <PublicRoute exact restricted={false} path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  
</BrowserRouter>
```

**PublicRoute:**

```
class PublicRoute extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            isSubscribed: false
        };
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        console.log("loading");

        const isLoginCheck = await isLogin();
        const isSubscribedCheck = await isSubscribed();

        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            isAuthenticated: isLoginCheck || false,
            isSubscribed: isSubscribedCheck || false
        })

    }

    render() {
        const { component: Component, restricted, ...rest } = this.props;
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={props => (
                    //If a user is authenticated, subscribed and the route is restricted, redirect to dashboard
                    this.state.isAuthenticated && this.state.isSubscribed && restricted ? (
                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    ) : this.state.loading ? (
                        //If loading, show a loading component (placeholder currently)
                        <div>LOADING</div>
                    ) : this.state.isAuthenticated && (!this.state.isSubscribed) ? (
                        //If the user is authenticated, but not subscribed. redirect to landing
                        <Redirect to="/landing" />
                        
                    ) :
                                (
                                    //Else redirect to the component.
                                    <Component {...props} />
                                ))

                }
            />
        );
    }
}

export default PublicRoute;
```

**Landing:**

```
   class Landing extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('component mounted');
    }
    render() {
        console.log('Component was called');
        return (
            <h1>Landing page - not a valid subscriber. </h1>
        )
    }
}


export default Landing;
```

Thanks!